# Second ORDER BY criteria, how to restrict it to one value only?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have hard time to design a proper SQL request, I need to select and order (ascending) "scores" summed up over several dates (here 2 dates), and WHEN EQUALITY, I need to order the scores according to one date only.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT SUM(score) 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE planning_date = "2021/09/16" AND planning_date = "2021/09/15" 
ORDER BY SUM(score), SUM(score (BUT only for the case of planning_date = "2021/09/16")) )
```

Any idea ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your query can't return any results. How can `planning_date` have two different values?

Comment: Should `AND` be `OR`?

Comment: And in MySQL you must use `YYYY-MM-DD` date literal format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AND` should be `OR` if you want to return results for two different dates. You can also use `IN` to match a list of dates.

Use a `CASE` expression inside `SUM()` to restrict the sum to a particular date.

```
SELECT SUM(score) 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE planning_date IN ("2021/09/16", "2021/09/15")
ORDER BY SUM(score), SUM(CASE WHEN planning_date = "2021/09/16" THEN score END)
```

Comment: MySQL. YYYY-MM-DD